# Why do I get a SettingWithCopyWarning when changing a pd dataframe inside a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my code for summing rows with identical index in pandas dataframes. When I do the same operations outside a function the SettingWithCopyWarning does not appear. So how should my function look like to avoid this message?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import collections

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=(4,5)), 
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'], index=['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'])

def remove_duplicated_rows_by_summing_them(table):
    duplicates = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(list(table.index)).items() if count > 1]
    for d in duplicates:
        summed_reads_per_col = np.array(table.loc[d,:].sum(axis=0))
        table = table.drop([d], axis=0)
        table.loc[d] = summed_reads_per_col
    return table

df = remove_duplicated_rows_by_summing_them(df)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify values later by `table.loc[d] = summed_reads_per_col` you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`table`), and that Pandas does warning.

Solution is use [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
table = table.drop([d], axis=0).copy()
```

But simplier is use instead your function `sum` per index values:

```
df = df.sum(level=0)
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
A     9     3     6     9     7
B    15     5     2    11    15
C     8     9     6     5     1
```